# Tensorflow exporting custom Estimator (defining serving_input_fn and PredictOutput)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

> I have created custom `tf.Estimator` for MNIST classification
>   (some convolution, dropout, batch normalization) and I would like to
>   save it using `export_savedmodel` (say for predictions).
>   Everything works except for the saving part.
>
> From what I have gathered around the web and docs I have to specify
>   `serving_input_fn` and `tf.estimator.PredictOutput` but I'm
>   unable to grasp my head around all of those (documentation and
>   examples look sparse as well).
>
> **INFO ABOUT PROBLEM:**
>
> 1. Error I am receiving: `ValueError: labels must not be None.`
> 2. Input layer shape: `input_layer = tf.reshape(features['x'], [-1, 28, 28, 1])`
> 3. `serving_input_fn` I am using:
>
>    ```
>    def serving_input_receiver_fn():
>        serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(
>            dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='input_tensors')
>        receiver_tensors = {'predictor_inputs': serialized_tf_example}
>        feature_spec = {'x': tf.FixedLenFeature([28, 28, 1], tf.float32)}
>        features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
>        return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, 
>                                                receiver_tensors)
>    ```
> 4. Predict Output function:
>
>    ```
>    export_outputs = {
>        'predict_output':
>         tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput({
>            'pred_output_classes': self.predictions,
>            'prob': tf.nn.softmax(self.logits),
>            }),
>        } return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
>        mode=tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT,
>        predictions={
>            'class': self.predictions,
>            'probabilities': tf.nn.softmax(self.logits),
>        },
>        export_outputs=export_outputs)
>    ```
> 5. Saving model (after training and evaluation):
>
>    ```
>    classifier.export_savedmodel(
>        './custom_model', serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
>    ```
>
> Correct code needed for exporting would be greatly appreciated (I'm
>   tired of unintuitive design of this library, so if you are past this
>   struggle please do rescue me :( ). Some explanation regarding why
>   this unintuitive thing has to go there would be awesome as well.
>
> **If you need some additional informations I'll provide them.**

Link to stack trace:

https://gist.github.com/vyzyv/885e7e63520332e5ee42f4bc332a877f

**PROBLEM SOLUTION**:

Can be useful information for others: **Do not calculate loss for prediction mode in tf.Estimator** (solution by @AlexandrePassos, see comments).

Comment: Can you share a stack trace of your error?

Comment: @AlexandrePassos Updated original post with stack trace.

Comment: The problem seems to be that your model_fn is always computing the loss even when mode==tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT

Comment: Thanks, that was it (few minor fixes were needed as well but otherwise this was the issue).